# How to deploy & run multiple war deployment in Jboss AS

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, jboss, war

How to deploy & run multiple war deployment in Jboss AS.
We have two different war in abc.war, xyz.war inside Jboss 5. How to start
by specific instance of war from command prompt. Looking for command.?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the JBoss version you are using. Jboss 7 offers command level interface (CLI) to do this. Please [check this link](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Application+deployment). Here is another related [detailed post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439609/undeploying-apps-in-jboss-application-server-from-the-command-line).